# Connect to docker_engine (named pipe) from a C# Service Fabric app on Windows

Tags: c#, docker, azure-service-fabric, docker-for-windows, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a Stateless Service Fabric project (.NET Core) that I need to kick off a Docker job from. I'm using `Docker.DotNet` and the following code works well in a small Console App, however will not work in Service Fabric:

```
var dockerClient = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine")).CreateClient();

// error occurs on next line (in Service Fabric)...
dockerClient.Images
    .CreateImageAsync(new ImagesCreateParameters
    {
        FromImage = "jbarlow83/ocrmypdf",
        Tag = "latest"
    },
        new AuthConfig(),
        new Progress<JSONMessage>());
```

I see this error in Service Fabric Explorer if I try to run it from the Stateless SF project:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.DotNet.DockerClient.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Client.ManagedHandler.d__33.MoveNext()
```

I'm not sure if this is actually a permission issue, or if it's related to how Service Fabric network isolation works.

I'm trying this on my local development instance, and this will eventually (hopefully) go to an on-premise setup.

Is there a way to access named pipes on the node that is hosting a SF application?  Or perhaps another suggested way to run Docker through a .NET Core SF application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing my `DockerClientConfiguration` line to no longer use named pipes, and instead use `http://localhost:2375`:

```
var dockerClient = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("http://localhost:2375")).CreateClient();
```

And then enabled **Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS** in the Docker CE General Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this when I ran into this issue today, and ended up stumbling onto a different solution if you don't want to switch away from the Named Pipe connection.  If you set up your Service Fabric service to run as a LocalSystem Account instead of the default account, it should work as well.

You can follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security) to change the Account your Stateless Service runs under in the Manifest

This works because according to [this article on Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-security-and-access-rights), only certain types of accounts get access to the Named Pipe, one of which is LocalSystem.

Comment: Do you know how we can create a new LocalSystem account?

Comment: Service Fabric should automatically handle the account for you if you follow the instructions in the first link above from my experience.